# Optimizing mysql configuration?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-optimization, my.cnf

I have a website with 100k+ daily visitors. We use MySQL 5.1.

Serving all these visitors and logging their data specially during rush hours put a lot of load on our server.

I just upgraded our server to EC2/c3.8xlarge    with vCPU=32, ECU= 108 and memory = 60G

Any suggestion about how I should setup my mysql configuration to optimize our usage?

I know this is a very broad question and depend on the nature of the load, the answer might be different, but I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Without seeing your db nor your web code, I only can advice you to try to optimize your queries in order to have a less traffic, optimize indexes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider updating to MySQL 5.5 (or higher) since they included the performance_schema since that version. That'll help you monitor events alot better and determine were you have to improve on your configuration regarding performance.

Other than that i guess you check some memory settings in your my.cnf. I'm not really read into it but i think some variables you can check regarding performance are:
key_buffer_size,
table_cache,
sort_buffer_size,
read_buffer_size,

Upgrading your server is always good but i think you have to tune MySQL towards that aswell